# What is the best way for a rails noob to learn rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've been reading as many tutorials and watching all kinds of videos on learning rspec... I've perused the rails guides on testing and the rspec docs too. Don't feel like its clicked yet and I'm just roaming in the dark.

Does anyone have some recommendations for a good overview of rspec and testing rails apps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [The Rspec Book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book)
2. [Codeschool's Testing With Rspec](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/testing-with-rspec)
3. [Peepcode's RSpec casts](https://peepcode.com/screencasts/rspec)

And of course the immortal railscasts.com

Answer (score 7):

Just start writing specs and you will feel the power.
Also I recommend a nice guide http://betterspecs.org/ and [Rspec book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book)

Answer (score 4):

Try watching some casts. I recommend [how i test](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test) cast of Ryan Bates's

more: [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=rspec)

Answer (score 2):

I got a good feel for it when I did Michael Hartl's tutorial:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/